Logging user commands
So I am working on this fun project and I've been trying to setup logging for user commands for the past 3 days but nothing seems to work. So for the starters I use Ubuntu 22.04 which runs inside of a docker container. And the way this project works is u have a backend which has some configured endpoints which execute linux commands when called. Now I am trying to setup a logger so that admins can view the actions users do on the frontend.
Tried snoopy but I just couldn't understand it. Then I tried auditd but I couldn't even start it. In short it was recognized as service but when I tried starting it with $service auditd start, it just wouldn't start and I couldn't figure out why. Last one I tried was rsyslog which "works". Well kind of, when I run command $logger  it logs but for some reason no matter what I do I can't make it to log all commands users run. I'll also mention that rsyslog is not recognized as a service in my implementation but I don't know why. So I have to start it with $rsyslogd command. Now I know that logging every command may not be optimal but its just a small project and I am trying to do it without a database.
So my question would be, did someone ran into the similar problem and knows how to make it work or perhaps know of any other ways to log user commands into a file?
Also, this solution didn't work as rsyslog is not recognized as service: How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?

Options which use systemctl also don't work as it is not recognized as command.
My Dockerfile looks like this if that helps:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /data/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /data/app/requirements.txt

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3 python3-dev python3-pip
RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install curl

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /data/app/requirements.txt
RUN apt install -y bash
RUN apt install sudo


SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY ./endpoints /data/app/endpoints
COPY ./jsons /data/app/jsons
COPY ./models /data/app/models
COPY ./modules_taken_from_jakub_kuska /data/app/modules_taken_from_jakub_kuska
COPY ./scripts /data/app/scripts
COPY ./temp_files /data/app/temp_files
COPY ./utils /data/app/utils
COPY ./main.py /data/app/main.py
COPY ./admins ../../etc/sudoers.d/

#COPY audit.rules /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules

RUN useradd -mU Company_bot && echo "Company_bot:HardPassword" | chpasswd && for group in end_users CEOs Management Workers;do groupadd ${group};done && usermod -aG end_users,CEOs,Management,Workers Company_bot && useradd -mU Admin && echo "Admin:Admin" | chpasswd && groupadd administrator && usermod -aG administrator Admin

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0" , "--port", "8005"]


If I understand it write, you have a web app written (apparently in Python), which executes commands based on user input, and you want to log what gets executed? Then why not just modify your web app to do something like log.info("user executed blah blah") just before you do os.system() or subprocess.run() or whatever it is you use to execute commands? Your webapp already has all the information needed.

Did something similar. Thanks for the input
